# User ID Warning

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, migration, administration

Joomla 3.4.1

I am using EasyBlog and have migrated all of my posts from Site A to Site B.

I did this by selecting all of the relevant tables in Site A and importing to Site B (via phpmyadmin). All of the migrated posts do appear in my new Site B however there is one issue, the post doesn't show the author info.

The following warning appears (both in front-end and back-end);

> Warning
>
> JUser: :_load: Unable to load user with ID: 438
>
> JUser: :_load: Unable to load user with ID: 437

I only have two users in my Joomla site. When I look under Users > User manager their ID's are 737 and 738.

Presumable I need to change these to 437 and 438? Do I simply change these in the `_users` table or is there something else I must also do?

My Super user is ID 737

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any extension that interacts with users in any way, shop or form, requires the `#__users` table. It sounds like you have migrated the EasyBlog data, but forgot to migrate the data from the `#__users` table on the old site to the new site.

This would explain why the user ID doesn't exist and the error you're receiving.

You need to export and import the following tables:

- `#__users`
- `#__user_usergroup_map`
- `#__usergroups` (only if you have custom usergroups)